# Why shiny breaks when messaging an error?

Tags: r, shiny, error-handling, try-catch

This simple line seems to cause no harm:

```
tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { message(e) } )
```

But it breaks inside a shiny app while those two lines work perfectly:

```
tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { print(e) } )
tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { message(e |> as.character()) } )
```

I cannot figure what is happening here?

---

#### Minmal app

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
 actionButton("p", "error with print"),
 actionButton("m", "error with message"),
 actionButton("c", "error with message as character")  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$p, {
    tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { print(e) } )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$m, {
    tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { message(e) } )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$c, {
    tryCatch( stop(), error = function(e) { message(e |> as.character()) } )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Shiny installs its own message handler, and it doesn’t seem to handle arguments of type `simpleError` correctly; you can cause the same issue by directly executing `message(simpleError("test"))` inside a Shiny app. — At any rate, it’s probably a better idea to use `message(conditionMessage(e))` in real code (instead of `message(e)`) when `e` is a condition object.

Comment: Not an explanation, but you can avoid the breakage by replacing `message(...)` with `print(.makeMessage(...))`.

Comment: If you modify the 2nd `observeEvent()` with `tryCatch(stop("my error m"), error = function(e) { browser():message(e)     }   )`  you see that `e`  is a `structure` : `dput(e)` give `structure(list(message = "my error m", call = doTryCatch(return(expr), 
    name, parentenv, handler)), class = c("simpleError", "error", 
"condition"))` and `message()` seems to don't like that. Look at `e$message` and `geterrmessage()` : but `print(.makeMessage(e))`, from Limey, could be simpler to use. In the doc ".makeMessage is a utility used by message, warning and stop to generate a text message."

Comment: Type `message` without `()`: you will see the source of `message()`: it is much more complicated that simple function that displays a string.